# How to extract timestamps and estimate the difference between pairs of them

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = data.frame(c("2012-12-30 08:01:01","2012-12-30 09:05:02"),
                c("2012-12-30 09:01:00","2012-12-30 10:15:00"))
colnames(df) = c("start","end")
```

Then I extract timestamps as follows:

```
df$time_start = substr(df$start,12,19)
df$time_end = substr(df$end,12,19)
```

The type of `time_start` and `time_end` is `character` (`class(df$time_start)`).

Now I want to create a new column `duration` that will contain the difference between `time_start` and `time_end`:

```
library("lubridate")

df$duration <- seconds_to_period(as.numeric(difftime(df$time_start, dfs$time_end, units = "secs"))
```

I get the folloiwng error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I tried to parse `time_start` and `time_end` to `POSIXct`, but then I get dates again:

```
df$time_start_parsed = as.POSIXct(df$time_start,format="%H:%M:%S")

df

                start                 end time_start   time_start_parsed
1 2012-12-30 08:01:01 2012-12-30 09:01:00   09:01:00 2016-10-19 09:01:00
2 2012-12-30 09:05:02 2012-12-30 10:15:00   10:15:00 2016-10-19 10:15:00
```

Comment: What about `difftime(as.POSIXct(df$end),as.POSIXct(df$start),units="secs")`?

Comment: Maybe `library(lubridate); df$duration <- difftime(ymd_hms(df$end), ymd_hms(df$start))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: This works. Thx.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: Could you pls publish the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's request, converting comment into an answer:

```
library(lubridate)
df$duration <- difftime(ymd_hms(df$end), ymd_hms(df$start))
```